# Javascript code to detect arabic translation and choose arabic stylesheet

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, translation, arabic

I'm working on a website with country maps see here: http://defenddefenders.huritech.org/
The challenge is in that it has an arabic translation option, and this when chosen seriously distorts my css even worse, the image map.
Right now I'm looking for a javascript solution which will Detect that when the arabic translation option is selected, it chooses a different stylesheet, say ar_style.css to display instead.

I'm not too good with javascript, any help?  will appreciate, thanks.
The translation is being done by the transposh plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that page has is a body tag like this:

```
<body class="home page page-id-1011 page-template page-template-template-magazine-php gecko two-col-left width-960 two-col-left-960">
```

When I switch to Arabic I get:

```
<body class="rtl home page page-id-1011 page-template page-template-template-magazine-php chrome two-col-left width-960 two-col-left-960">
```

So you have the CSS to change this stuff already.

If you specify a style like:

```
body div { /* something */ }
body.rtl div { /* something else */ }
```

Then you can put an override in the `body.rtl div` for your arabic users. Perhaps you could, for the elements that look wrong, do:

```
body.rtl div#whatever {
    direction: ltr;
}
```

That way, you force it to change direction. Really though, that's a band-aid. You need to provide better styles for your Arabic users.

Comment: This worked like charm :) I'm so grateful to you and this whole community in general. You have no idea how many sleepless nights this arabic issue has given me. Thanks @artlung !

Answer (score -2):

I hope this PHP code can help you

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css" type="text/css" />
<?php if($language->language == "he" || $language->language == "ar") : ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/rtl.css" type="text/css" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

or you may want to look here

http://jasonrobb.com/v2/2009/09/03/how-to-flip-the-text-direction-layout-of-a-website-with-css/index.html

Comment: The previous suggestion worked. Thank yo still, for taking your time to help!